# names function in R not working as expected

Tags: r, vector, names

I have a vector named v as follows:

```
> v


Moe  Larry  Curly  Harry  Tevez Kagiso  Harry Sierra 


10     20     30     40     50     60     70     NA    110     NA   1110   1210
```

Now, I am trying to replace the empty names at v[9:12] with a 4 element vector, using :

```
names(v[9:12]) = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

The command runs OK, but when I print the vector v, the result is same as before.

Any suggestions, where am I wrong ?

Earlier when I had, v as below, it had worked OK.

`> v
   Moe  Larry  Curly  Harry  Tevez Kagiso

    10     20     30     40     50     60     70     NA`

I had used :

`> names(v)[7:8] = c("Harry","Sierra")`

`> v
   Moe  Larry  Curly  Harry  Tevez Kagiso  Harry Sierra 
    10     20     30     40     50     60     70     NA`

Comment: You assign to the names of the subset. You want to assign to the subset of the names: `names(v)[9:12]`

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: Please try to understand my comment. Simply use `names(v)[9:12] = c("A", "B", "C", "D")`

Comment: Ohh, I get it !

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning names to the new vector `110, NA, 1110, 1210`.

Try

```
names(v) <- c(names(v)[1:8], "A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Comment: I earlier tried with names(v)[7:8], it worked OK. I have updated in the question.